# In testNG, do we have a way to run depends On Methods as a part of parent method's data driven test cycle?

Tags: testng

In testNG, do we have a way to run depends On Methods as a part of parent method's data driven test cycle?

Ex. Suppose We need to test login and logout scenario for each user as in below code, How can achieve this scenario with testng

```
@Test(dataProvider = "userDataProvider")
    public void testLogin(User user){
     //Some Logic goes here
    }

 @Test(dependsOnMethods="testLogin")
    public void testLogOut(){
     //Some Logic goes here
    }

    @DataProvider(name ="userDataProvider")
    public Object[][] provideData() {

        return new Object[][]{
                {new User("user1","user1")},
                {new User("user2","user2")},
                {new User("user3","user3")},
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using TestNG factories that are powered by data provider.

Here's a sample that shows you how to do this.

```
public class TestClass {
    private User user;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "userDataProvider")
    public TestClass(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
         //Some Logic goes here that uses this.user
    }

    @Test (dependsOnMethods = "testLogin")
    public void testLogout() {
        //Some Logic goes here that uses this.user
    }

    @DataProvider(name ="userDataProvider")
    public static Object[][] provideData() {
        return new Object[][] {
            { new User("user1","user1") },
            { new User("user2","user2") },
            { new User("user3","user3") }
        };
    }
}
```